# Application Insights wants me to use Javascript with a fixed JSON key

Tags: javascript, json, azure, azure-application-insights

When I go into the Azure Application Insights resource for my Dev web app, and go to view Usage, I see a link that says 'Learn how to collect page view data'.

The link gives me the code below, but it has a fixed instrumentationKey set as a JSON variable. I would like it to use the web.config AppSettings value of iKey.

I can get the iKey into a javascript variable, but how do I get it into JSON?

Is there a better way to use Application Insights with the app.config iKey?

```
var iKey = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["iKey"].ToString() %>';
var appInsights = window.appInsights || function (config) {
    function r(config) {
        t[config] = function () {
            var i = arguments;
            t.queue.push(function () {
                t[config].apply(t, i)
            })
        }
    }
    var t = {
        config: config
    },
      u = document,
      e = window,
      o = "script",
      s = u.createElement(o),
      i, f;
    for (s.src = config.url || "//az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js", u.getElementsByTagName(o)[0].parentNode.appendChild(s), t.cookie = u.cookie, t.queue = [], i = ["Event", "Exception", "Metric", "PageView", "Trace"]; i.length;) r("track" + i.pop());
    return r("setAuthenticatedUserContext"), r("clearAuthenticatedUserContext"), config.disableExceptionTracking || (i = "onerror", r("_" + i), f = e[i], e[i] = function (config, r, u, e, o) {
        var s = f && f(config, r, u, e, o);
        return s !== !0 && t["_" + i](config, r, u, e, o), s
    }), t
}({
    instrumentationKey: "1x1111x1-1x1x-1x1x-xx11-xxxxxxxxxxxx" // I would like to use iKey here
});

window.appInsights = appInsights;
appInsights.trackPageView();
```

Comment: Why can't you replace the "1xx1xx1-1..." with `iKey`?

Comment: I get this message:  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Invalid instrumentation key)
ai.0.js:1 AI (Internal): NONUSRACT_OnError message:"Failed to send telemetry." props:"{message:{\itemsReceived\:3,\itemsAccepted\:0,\errors\:[{\index\:0,\statusCode\:400,\message\:\Invalid instrumentation key\},{\index\:1,\statusCode\:400,\message\:\Invalid instrumentation key\},{\index\:2,\statusCode\:400,\message\:\Invalid instrumentation key\}]}}"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application Insights page view code gives me client side errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36633131/application-insights-page-view-code-gives-me-client-side-errors)

Comment: wouldn't your code just be `instrumentationKey: iKey` in your example?  it seems like that should work.  i presume if you debug, the value of iKey in js isn't what you expect it to be. 
can you paste in, or edit your snippet above to show the exact ikey as it is in the code?  ikey isn't a secret (anyone who sees your page can see the ikey in code).

Comment: Make sure you're using the right key, I spent almost an hour tearing my hair out to realise I was using the subscription key instead of instrumentation key...