# Application Insights page view code gives me client side errors

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

When I go into the Azure Application Insights resource for my Dev web app, and go to view Usage, I see a link that says 'Learn how to collect page view data'.

The link gives me the code below.

```
var appInsights = window.appInsights || function (config) {
    function r(config) {
        t[config] = function () {
            var i = arguments;
            t.queue.push(function () {
                t[config].apply(t, i)
            })
        }
    }
    var t = {
        config: config
    },
      u = document,
      e = window,
      o = "script",
      s = u.createElement(o),
      i, f;
    for (s.src = config.url || "//az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js", u.getElementsByTagName(o)[0].parentNode.appendChild(s), t.cookie = u.cookie, t.queue = [], i = ["Event", "Exception", "Metric", "PageView", "Trace"]; i.length;) r("track" + i.pop());
    return r("setAuthenticatedUserContext"), r("clearAuthenticatedUserContext"), config.disableExceptionTracking || (i = "onerror", r("_" + i), f = e[i], e[i] = function (config, r, u, e, o) {
        var s = f && f(config, r, u, e, o);
        return s !== !0 && t["_" + i](config, r, u, e, o), s
    }), t
}({
    instrumentationKey: "1x1111x1-1x1x-1x1x-xx11-xxxxxxxxxxxx" 
});

window.appInsights = appInsights;
appInsights.trackPageView();
```

When I run/debug my page, I receive these messages in the browser console window:

> POST http://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track 400 (Invalid instrumentation key) - dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track:1
>   AI (Internal): NONUSRACT_OnError message:"Failed to send telemetry." props:"{message:{\itemsReceived:3,\itemsAccepted:0,\errors:[{\index:0,\statusCode:400,\message:\Invalid instrumentation key},{\index:1,\statusCode:400,\message:\Invalid instrumentation key},{\index:2,\statusCode:400,\message:\Invalid instrumentation key}]}}" - ai.0.js:1

In my actual code, I am using the key they provided me in the sample, which matches the key in properties. **Why do I receive these errors?**

*More background data:*
I have an `AppInsights.js` file with the above code, and load it via my BundleConfig in the `<head>` of my `_Layout.cshtml` file like this:

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src='{0}' defer></script>", "~/bundles/scripts")
```

We do need the defer tag for some of the scripts we load.

Comment: 1. Have you tried removing possible hidden characters in the provided ikey?
2. Is this a new application in Application Insights?

Comment: Can you check in fiddler/browser dev console what instrumentationkey is passed to dc.services.visualstudio.com (you'll need to look at the payload which is sent in the POST request)